# How significant is the benefit of cv2.cornersubpix() while performing calibration?

Tags: python, computer-vision, camera-calibration, opencv

So I am performing calibration as showed [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html), the only difference is that I am inverting the image `[gray = cv.bitwise_not(gray)]` before detecting chessboard pattern on it.

I am getting different un-distorted images based on usage of [cv2.cornerSubPix](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d92/tutorial_corner_subpixels.html)
and cv2.CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL flag.

I will be fine without using cv2.cornerSubPix but I want to know if I am loosing something like accurancy on distortion or matrix and if yes, how significant is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How significant is it? Impossible to answer unless you explain what you are calibrating the camera for.

Are you going to make one pretty picture that people are going to look at for its aesthetic value, from a distance where their eyes cannot resolve a few pixels, much less half of one? Then sure, you can get away with an approximate and likely biased calibration without subpixel feature estimation.

Are you going to calibrate the camera of an artillery telemeter for an antiarcraft gun that's supposed to shoot at an attacking enemy jet a mile away? You better get rid of as much calibration error as you can, or your people will die.

If you really want to see what difference cv2.cornerSubpix makes for your use case, calibrate with and without, then plot residuals for all the target corners in all images as point clouds. You should see a "tighter" cloud around (0, 0) for the subpixel-using case.

Also, try calibrating "from scratch" several times with different patterns of target motion relative to the camera, again with and without using subpixel corners: you will likely see that the calibrated camera parameters stay more consistent across calibrations when you use subpixel features.